# Solr How to store limited amount of text instead of fully body

Tags: indexing, solr

As per our business requirement, I need to index full story body (consider it for a news story for example) but in the Solr query result I need to return a preview text (say, first 400 characters) to bind to the target news listing page.

As I know there are 2 options in schema file for any field stored=false/true. Only way I can see as of now is I set it to true and take the full story body in result and then excerpt text to preview manually, but this seems not to be practical because (1) It will occupy GBs of space on disc for storing full body and (2) the json response becomes very heavy. (The query result can return 40K/50K stories).

I also know about limiting the number of records but for some reasons we need complete result at once.

Any help for achieving this requirement efficiently ?

Answer (score 0):

In order to display just 400 characters in the news overview, you can simply use [Solr Highlighting Feature](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Highlighting) and specify the number of snippets and their size. For instance for [Standard highlighter](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Standard+Highlighter) you have parameters:

> **hl.snippets**: Specifies maximum number of highlighted snippets to generate per field. It is possible for any number of snippets from
> zero to this value to be generated. This parameter accepts per-field
> overrides.
>
> **hl.fragsize**: Specifies the size, in characters, of fragments to consider for highlighting. 0 indicates that no fragmenting should be
> considered and the whole field value should be used. This parameter
> accepts per-field overrides.

If you want to index everything but store only part of the text then you can follow the solution advised [here](http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/limit-stored-field-size-td4284356.html) in Solr Community.